# Using HTML picture element with ACF and Gutenberg

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have created a custom Gutenberg block with ACF pro. I have 3 image uploaders "small, medium and large", I want to use the html picture element to display "Small-Image" on smaller screens, without loading the other image sizes. Images are displaying on the front end but once I add them to the picture element the are not displaying and everything after the php command is displaying on the frontend.

```
<div class="row">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 650px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $small_image ); ?>" alt="Small">
            <source media="(max-width: 900px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $medium_image ); ?>" alt="Medium">
            <source media="(max-width: 1790px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $large_image ); ?>" alt="Large">
            <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
        </picture>
</div>
```

" alt="Small"> is being displayed on the frontend.

I have tried using

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $small_image, 'full' ); ?>


<source media="(max-width: 650px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $small_image ); ?>" alt="Small">


<source media="(max-width: 650px)" srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url((int)get_post_meta($post->ID,'small_image',true)); ?>" alt="Small">

and 

<source media="(max-width: 650px)" srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_id((int)get_post_meta($post->ID,'small_image',true)); ?>" alt="Small">
```

Themes -> Template Parts -> Blocks -> Responsive image uploader -> image-uploader.php

```
<?php
$small_image = get_field('small_image') ?: 295;
$medium_image = get_field('medium_image') ?: 295;
$large_image = get_field('large_image') ?: 295;

$text = get_field('testimonial') ?: 'Your testimonial here...';
?>

<section id="upload_image" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">
           <h3> Small Image </h3>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $small_image, 'full' ); ?>
            <h3>Medium Image</h3>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $medium_image, 'full' ); ?>
            <h3>Large Image</h3>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $large_image, 'full' ); ?>
        </div> 


        <div class="row">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 650px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $small_image ); ?>" alt="Small">
            <source media="(max-width: 900px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $medium_image ); ?>" alt="Medium">
            <source media="(max-width: 1790px)" srcset="<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $large_image ); ?>" alt="Large">
            <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
        </picture>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 650px)" srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url((int)get_post_meta($post->ID,'small_image',true)); ?>" alt="Small">
            <source media="(max-width: 900px)" srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url((int)get_post_meta($post->ID,'medium_image',true)); ?>" alt="Medium">
            <source media="(max-width: 1790px)" srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url((int)get_post_meta($post->ID,'small_image',true)); ?>" alt="Large">
            <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
        </picture>
        </div>



    </div>
</section>
```

Functions.php

```
add_action('acf/init', 'lil_define_block');
function lil_define_block() {

    // check function exists
    if( function_exists( 'acf_register_block' ) ) {

        // register a fun facts block
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name'              => 'responsive-image-uploader',
            'title'             => __( 'Responsive Image Uploader' ),
            'description'       => __('Upload images that display on different screensizes.'),
            'render_template'   => 'template-parts/blocks/image-uploader/image-uploader.php',
            'category'          => 'layout',
            'icon'              => 'nametag',
            'keywords'          => array( 'images', 'picture', 'responsive', 'acf' ),
        ));
    }
}
```

I want to have 3 seperate cropped images display according to screen size.